Asus laptop: keyboard and wifi not working
After installing Ubuntu 24.04 on my Asus Vivobook 14 keyboard,wifi and Bluetooth stopped working.
I need help.

Given you've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details, we can only provide generic advice...   If using a LTS release of Ubuntu, there are kernel stack options, with the default set by your installation media for example  (changing kernel stack causes kernel modules (aka drivers) to also change.

Check your system firmware is 100% current and if it is not, update it. (This ought to be a FAQ.)
